# Как подключить плагин JaCoCo в режиме генерации отчётов (обрушать сборку по покрытию не нужно)

Tags: java, github, maven, jacoco

У меня есть pom.xml со следующим кодом (он ниже), На репозиторий подключено Github Actions и при попытке загрузить на гит изменения в тестах, сборка обрушается, а ее не нужно обрушать. Как изменить кусок кода с jacoco,чтобы сборка не обрушалась?

```
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>CLASS</element>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>*Test</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>1.0</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <maximum>1.0</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<execution>
                <id>default-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>CLASS</element>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>*Test</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>1.0</minimum>
                                </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <maximum>1.0</maximum>
                                    </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```

Если у тебя код не покрыт 100% тестами, то благодаря конфигам выше, сборка обрушается, ты можешь убрать это если у тебя код с тестами, но не 100%, уменьши 100% покрытия.